# java.sql.sqlexception method not supported executemany()

Tags: python, hadoop, jaydebeapi

jaydebeapi  executemany() method is not working for big csv file writing to hadoop table.

Can someone please give example to writing csv data to Hive table?

Comment: "Hadoop table" is not a thing. Did you mean Hive? You should use PySpark for this, not a JDBC Driver

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am new here so i was not aware about hive table ..can you please suggest how to insert into hive table through pyspark and why jaydebeapi is not good option for this problem

Comment: Hadoop itself has nothing related to JDBC, so what JDBC connection are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

> big csv file writing to hadoop

Unclear why you're trying to use JDBC for this

`pip install pyspark`

```
import pyspark 

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

spark = SparkSession.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("file.csv")
df.write.parquet("hdfs:///tmp/upload")
```

Alternatively, if you're using Apache Hive, then see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html